# Help proving $\text{odd}(m^2-n^2)\implies \text{odd}((m+n)^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

I need some help proving the following proposition:

$\text{odd}(m^2-n^2)\implies \text{odd}((m+n)^2)$

Since odd can be defined as:

$\text{odd}(x):\exists k \in \mathbb{Z} \; x=2k+1$

I can write the above statement as:

$\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\;m^2-n^2=2k+1\implies\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}\;(m+n)^2=2k+1$

I can write the right side $(m+n)^2$ as $m^2+n^2+2mn$ which looks kind of similar to the left side, but with opposite signs and a $2mn$ on the end.

Can I say that since $m^2-n^2$ is odd, then $m^2+n^2$ is also odd? And then since $2mn$ is always going to be even, that $m^2+n^2 + 2mn$ is Odd $+$ Even which is Odd?

Comment: Look at this: $m^2-n^2 = (m+n)^2 - 2(n^2 + mn)$

Comment: I see how that's true, but I don't see how that gets me anywhere closer to showing that it's the same as $(m+n)^2$.

Comment: @grimrader22 read more carefully. Is $2(n^2+mn)$ odd or even?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Even no? $\text{Even}(x): \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\;2k = x$ and $\text{Odd}(x): \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\;2k+1 = x$. So since $2(n^2+mn)$ is of the form $2k$, it is even?

Comment: Right. Now, can you prove that $even\pm even=even$, $odd\pm odd=even$ and $even \pm odd=odd$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(m+n)^2=m^2+n^2+2mn=m^2-n^2+2(n^2+mn)$

Comment: So once I have $m^2-n^2+n(n^2+mn)$, where do I go? It's not the same as $m^2-n^2$, and I don't see how it fits in with the definition of odd.

Comment: Since odd, $m^2-n^2=2k+1$. Hence $(m+n)^2=2(k+n^2+mn)+1$ by above equality

Comment: I hope you realize that the reverse implication is also true.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid, but where did $k+n^2+mn$ come from. I see that it's in the $m^2-n^2+2(n^2+mn)$, but how can you just omit the rest and only use $n^2+mn$? and then there's a $k$ that comes in out of nowhere?

Comment: Since $m^2 - n^2$ is odd, there is a $k$ such that $m^2 - n^2 = 2k + 1$. You can then rearrange that, to get that $(m+n)^2 = 2k + 1 + 2n^2 + 2mn = 2(k + n^2 + mn) + 1$. So then, you've written it in a form that shows its oddness.

Comment: @ConMan I see what your saying in the first sentence. but I don't see how $(m+n)^2$ can be written how you say. It expands to $m^2+n^2+2mn$, which as done above can also be written as $m^2-n^2+2(n^2+mn)$. How can you just add the last bit of that ($2(n^2+mn)$) onto the end of $2k+1$?

Comment: Because we've stated that $m^2 - n^2 = 2k + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$m^2-n^2$ is odd iff $m,n$ have different parity, which happens iff $m+n$ is odd, in turn iff $(m+n)^2$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

$m^{2} - n^{2}= (m-n) (m+n) \equiv 1$ (mod 2) by definition as being odd.

Thus $(m+n) \not \equiv 0$ (mod 2)

Thus $(m+n) \equiv 1$  (mod 2)

Thus $(m+n)(m+n) \equiv 1$  (mod 2)

Thus  $(m+n)^{2} \equiv 1$  (mod 2),  and is therefore odd.